# Renaming files via Assets

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets

I'm having a really odd issue with Assets. The problem is that we don't seem to be able to rename files - right clicking gives only the delete option. We're sure this worked before, but a) we can't prove it and b) if so, I don't know before 'what'.

Have discovered that if I upload a temporary image into Assets, the right click > rename option is available again (on the image I want to rename originally, as well as on the newly uploaded image).

If I then delete the temporary image, we're back to square one - no option to rename images, only delete.

Anyone have an idea what this might be?

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: You probably already do but make sure ur running the latest assets module + extension. Had similar a while ago running module updater with latest build sorted it

Comment: Andy, Stuart is right on this one. Assets 2.0 to 2.0.5 had this intermittent bug. Updating to 2.1 should solve this issue for you.

Comment: I should know better than to ask a question about a module without first testing if the latest release fixes it - thanks chaps.

Answer (score 2):

Assets 2.0 to 2.0.5 had this intermittent bug. Updating to 2.1 should solve this issue.

(Thanks to stuartmcd69 and Andris Sevcenko for this answer)